# Run bitcore-node as a service in the background in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, service, daemon, bitcore, bitpay

I successfully installed bitcore and able to run with the bitcore-node start. But I want to run it as service in the background.

> Installation Step of Bitcore-node.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install python
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev build-essential
npm install -g bitcore-node (https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node)
```

On Running `bitcore-node start`its working perfectly

> I created a service in the `/etc/systemd/system`

```
[Unit]
Description=bitcored.service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
Environment="PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/usr/bin"
ExecStart=/root/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/bitcore-node/bin/bitcore-node
ExecReload=/bin/kill -2 $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> On Executing the command `sudo service bitcore status` , I am getting
>   following Error.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

```
# install pm2
npm install pm2 -g

# go into your project and start it with pm2
cd mynode
pm2 start bitcore -- start

# check the logs that all runs smoothly
pm2 logs

# if everything runs fine 
# can setup the script to run on boot/reboot
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

[More info](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/)